# Orthogonality of Eigenvectors of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-q & -2p
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that has eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm} = -p \pm\sqrt{p^2-q}$

This means I can choose a particular basis in my vector space where
$A = S^{-1}\text{diag}\{\lambda_-, \lambda_+\}S$
where $S$ is a unitary matrix that can diagonalize $A$.

My question has to do with the eigenvectors of A, which I found to be
$$
v_{\pm}=\begin{pmatrix}-1/\lambda_{\pm}, 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
What confuses me is that these eigenvectors are not orthogonal to one another. Shouldn't they be?

** Edit 1: I had to flip the bottom row of my matrix A

** Edit 2: Coming from a physics background, I am only familiar with unitary transformations that can diagonalize a matrix. I suppose my transformation matrix $S$ need not be unitary, but it should be some invertable matrix that can diagonlize $A$.

Comment: Are you sure about your matrix (or alternatively, of your eigenvalues)? I think the bottom row should be flipped...

Comment: You are absolutely right about the bottom row. Let me fix that in an edit @Philip

Comment: @Philip I didn't calculate S. But since I know how to find the eigenvalues of $A$, I know there must exist some $S$ that allows me to diagonlize $A$.  Would calculating $S$ explicitly reveal why my eigenvectors are not orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem arising from the fact that your eigenvectors are not orthogonal. Recall that by definition you can diagonalize an operator $A$ if there exists a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ (with no orthogonality requirement). It's not even required that there is some inner product defined on $V$, which allows us to talk about diagonalization and canonical forms without this extra structure.

However, if your operator $A$ is symmetric and there is some inner product defined on $V$, then we can show that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ associated with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively, then $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle = 0$.

In fact:

$$\lambda_1\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=\langle A v_1, v_2\rangle =\langle v_1, Av_2\rangle=\lambda_2\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle$$

and since $\lambda_1\not=\lambda_2$, it follows that $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$.